# using 'case $1 in' to read command options- multiple flags after dash, and handling unusual flags?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I am making a bash script which uses both long options and short flags. Since I want long options, I can't use `getopts`. I tried using the following code:

```
while test -n "$1"; do
  case "$1" in
        -o|--override)  NO_CHANGE=yes;shift 1;;
        -r|--reset)     OV_RESET=yes;shift 1;;
        -h|--help)      hthemehelp;shift 1;;
        *)              break;;
  esac
done
```

This works when I invoke it like `myscr -o -r` or `myscr -h`, but when I try `myscr -or` the program just runs it's normal behavior, and running `myscr -or -h` it exits the loop before it gets to `-h`. Replacing `break` with `continue` just causes `myscr -or` and `myscr -or -h` to hang.

Comment: How small are you talking about? I have a `#!/bin/sh` library that takes 2 shell scripts to implement that covers parameters completely. I could pastebin it for you if you'd like.

Comment: My intention is to use no external libraries and to include everything in one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
#!/bin/bash
pleasereset=1
while test -n "$1"; do
   pleaseshift=0
   [[ pleasereset -eq 1 ]] && thisvar=$1 && pleasereset=0;
   case "$thisvar" in
      -o*|--override) echo "override!"; pleaseshift=1;;
      -r*|--reset) echo "reset!"; pleaseshift=1;;
      -h*|--help) echo "help!"; pleaseshift=1;;
      *) break ;;
   esac
   if [[ "$pleaseshift" = "1" ]];
   then
      testvar=${thisvar##-}
      if [[ ${#testvar} -gt 1 ]] && [[ ! ${thisvar} = --* ]];
      then
         thisvar=-$( echo "$testvar" | cut -c 2- )
      else
         shift 1; pleasereset=1;
      fi
   fi
done
```

Note that at the first parameter that doesn't match any specific case, the parameter parsing will stop, so a `./foobar.sh -o --help -s -r` will not process the `-r`. This can be adjusted by changing the `*) break;;` line to error handling, but remember to put the `pleaseshift=1`!

Comment: how can I give credit in my script for this code?

Comment: I usually just do a `#Reference: http://superuser.com/questions/778549/using-case-1-in-to-read-command-options-multiple-flags-after-dash-and-handl/` line or something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's enough to add the line you want so:

```
while test -n "$1"; do
  case "$1" in
        -or|-ro)        OV_RESET=yes;NO_CHANGE=yes;shift 1;;
        -o|--override)  NO_CHANGE=yes;shift 1;;
        -r|--reset)     OV_RESET=yes;shift 1;;
        -h|--help)      hthemehelp;shift 1;;
        *)              break;;
  esac
done
```

or, more complex, you can put the `case` block in a function with the `shift 1` out of that block but still inside the while.
For the *doubled* options (`-or`, `-oh`, that are not one of the long ones, you can recursively call the same function for each letter from `case *)`... You need a flag if you have just processed `$1` as a long option. In this case however you expose your script tp bad behaviour due to missprint (e.g. if I write `-overrider I will process`-o -v -e -r -d`...)